# Danger of hidden html form uploading users local files without their knowledge

Tags: web-browser, javascript, html

Is there a danger that a webpage could have a hidden form with a file upload input and js script that would try and take a random guesses at files on a users system and attach them to the form and submit it ?

The js for instance could try and and submit the form multiple times trying for files like `/users/name/documents/finances.xls` or `/users/name/documents/creditcards.xls` obviously the list of files and locations to check for would have to be quite extensive and even then theres no guarantee.

Is this a danger or do modern browsers have procedures to prevent this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible for a web page to set the path of the file to be uploaded, the user has to select something or type it in.

Comment: ah ok, so these cant be altered via the DOM or by setting the `value=""` attribute as you are able to do with other `<input>` types - It seems to be confirmed here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input.